# ERROR: KeyError: key package_name [xxx-xxx-xxx] not found (in Julia)

Tags: julia

I have created a new Julia package from a template. I then went and used the UUID package to create a new UUID for the package via `UUIDs.uuid4()`. Now, when I try to do `using myPackage` I get the following error:

```
ERROR: KeyError: key myPackage [uuid-value] not found
Stacktrace:
  [1] getindex
    @ ./dict.jl:482 [inlined]
  [2] root_module
    @ ./loading.jl:979 [inlined]
  [3] require(uuidkey::Base.PkgId)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:945
  [4] require(into::Module, mod::Symbol)
    @ Base ./loading.jl:923
  [5] eval
    @ ./boot.jl:360 [inlined]
  [6] eval
    @ ./Base.jl:39 [inlined]
  [7] repleval(m::Module, code::Expr, #unused#::String)
    @ VSCodeServer ~/.vscode/extensions/julialang.language-julia-1.5.4/scripts/packages/VSCodeServer/src/repl.jl:157
  [8] (::VSCodeServer.var"#69#71"{Module, Expr, REPL.LineEditREPL, REPL.LineEdit.Prompt})()
    @ VSCodeServer ~/.vscode/extensions/julialang.language-julia-1.5.4/scripts/packages/VSCodeServer/src/repl.jl:123
  [9] with_logstate(f::Function, logstate::Any)
    @ Base.CoreLogging ./logging.jl:491
```

Am I missing a step here? I have the package dev'ed in my Julia 1.6 environment right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it turns out, I had not changed the module name in the main file so it was trying to load in a module different from the package name which was causing the issue.

Comment: When answering your own question, it might make sense to write it as if somebody else was answering your question. Perhaps something like this: "Check to see if you also changed the module name for your package in your source code."

Comment: Agreed, in this case, I had figured it out before the suggestion was made.